# Picture Likes without a Database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am working on something but currently stuck.

1. I want to display images from a directory which I was able to do with PHP code

```php
<?php
    foreach(glob('img/lookbok/*/{*.jpg,*.jpeg}',GLOB_BRACE) as $img){
        echo '
            <div class="col s12 m6 l4">
               <div class="card hoverable">
                   <div class="card-image">
                       <img src="'.$img.'"  class="materialboxed responsive-img"  alt="" data-caption="Send message on Whatsapp for price">
                       <a href="" class="halfway-fab btn-floating pink pulse">
                          <i class="material-icons">favorite</i>
                       </a>
                   </div>
                   <i class="like tiny pink-text material-icons thumbsup prefix " >thumb_up</i><span id="like">0 likes</span>
                   <div class="card-action">
                        <a href="https://wa.me/23480120276442" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp pink-text text-darken-1"> Chat for prices</i> </a>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
    }
?>
```

[image]

The hard part which I really need help on is getting the likes to function.

1. Is there a way to go about this without using MySQL considering that fact that it doesn't requires user registration or login.
2. Also I am welcoming any suggestion.
   I currently use PHP and JavaScript for my development

Comment: You won't be able to build this without some sort of Database/Central storage of some sort.

Comment: You could use external software if you do not wish to use a Database, for example, creating a Python/Java/C# emulator which you can then use Sockets to store and collect data but I'm pretty sure just using a Database is 10x faster

Comment: even if your users do not have to register, you still could use the database for storing image information and likes. You can use sqlite as well if mysql seems to be to much overhead. Or even use text files which stores the likes per image.

Comment: You can store likes in image EXIF metadata if readwrite access to images is possible.